# Dictionary's internal order changes after JSON.parse() inside of a XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: python, html, json, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Code for calling the endpoint directly:

```
def countSongsFull():
    for i in range(0, len(shArray)):
        for j in range(0, len(shArray[i])):  # For every song
            if shArray[i][j]['trackName'] == "Vintage Chanel (feat. Joey Bada$$, Kirk Knight, Meechy Darko & Zombie Juice)":
                shArray[i][j]['trackName'] = "Vintage Chanel (feat. Joey Badass, Kirk Knight, Meechy Darko & Zombie Juice)"
            track = shArray[i][j]['trackName']
            artist = shArray[i][j]['artistName']
            if track in songDict:
                songDict[track][1] += shArray[i][j]['msPlayed']
            else:
                songDict.update({track: [artist, shArray[i][j]['msPlayed']]})

    sortedList = OrderedDict(sorted(songDict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][1], reverse=True))
    return json.dumps(sortedList, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Output when calling the endpoint directly:

```
{"Unknown Track":["Unknown Artist",121091397],"Blind":["Korn",32389011],"Falling Away from Me":["Korn",31157418],"Hot Dog":["Limp Bizkit",30380901],"Closer":["Nine Inch Nails",29512377],"It's On!":["Korn",28081239],"Be Quiet and Drive (Far Away)":["Deftones",24715597],"Justin":["Korn",24513041],"Dirty":["Korn",24267603],"Psycho Holiday":["Pantera",24170972]}
```

XMLHTTPRequest Code:

```
var replyParse;
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('GET', '/cgi-bin/simpleData.py?songF=True', true);
    http.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            replyParse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(replyParse);
        }
    };
    http.send(null);
```

Console Output after the XMLHTTPRequest:

```
{745: Array(2), 1985: Array(2), 2002: Array(2), 3005: Array(2), 5200: Array(2), 90210: Array(2), Unknown Track: Array(2), Blind: Array(2), Falling Away from Me: Array(2), Hot Dog: Array(2), Closer: Array(2)}
```

Why does the order change after the XMLRequest and how can i correct this?

Comment: JSON is a text-based serialization format. json Objects represent maps from string keys to other json type values. In Python, typically, a `dict` is what is being serialized as a JSON Object. Python `dict` objects maintain insertion order, although, they still really aren't ordered data structures. Once something becomes a JSON object, you *really* must assume that there is no longer any guarantees about order. If you want ordered data, use a JSON Array. That being said, various libraries have various conventions about this, and ways to control how the keys are stored

Comment: IOW, the "correct" principled solution is, don't rely on JSON objects for order. If you must have order, use a JSON array, and when you deserialize it, build up whatever data structure you need from the resulting sequence in some post-processing step

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, i didnt think of doing it like that. Appreciate it